# Performance of select over order by case join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been wrestling with this for a while, in some cases below sql takes over 30min to execute on a table with 100k rows in `current` and about 10 is `pending`. This is a portion of a larger join statement that I have identified as being the culprit. Basically the purpose of the sql is to sort a join of `current` rows and copies of `pending` rows so that all pending rows are either at the top or bottom. It's part of a management of change framework. Any ideas how this could be done in a mannaer that performs consistently well? For the record in some cases the same sql runs in under 10sec on tables that have 10M rows and 100s of pending changes. The problem is compounded by the fact that sorting is done on the calculated field. Database is ms sql server 2008 R2.

Update: I'm adding the rest of the joins to show there is semi reason in the madness.

Again the sole purpose of this is to get a combination of current and pending records, to show how a future table will look like after changes has been approved, sorted so the changes are shown either at top or bottom (ASC or DSC on the hasPending), the extra Current2 join is to add some additional identifying data.

Generally it does what its supposed to be doing, fairly decent response times of a few seconds, 10 when reaching around 10M records, however is a few cases everything consistenly slows to a crawl, with responsetimes shooting up to 12-30min.

```
WITH [ResultPage] AS 
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN [Current].[ID] IN 
            (SELECT [CID] 
             FROM [Pending] AS p
             INNER JOIN [Current] ON [Current].[ID] like p.[CID] 
             WHERE (p.[User] = 'admin'))
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
       END ASC, 
       [Current].[ID] ASC) AS [RowID], 
    [Current].[ID], 
    CASE WHEN [Current].[ID] IN 
        (SELECT [CID] 
         FROM [Pending] AS p 
     INNER JOIN [Current]  ON [Current].[ID] like p.[CID] 
         WHERE (p.[User] = 'admin'))
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS [HasPending] 
FROM [Current] 
INNER JOIN [Current2] AS [Table2] ON ([Current].[T2ID] = [Table2].[ID])
SELECT [ResultPage].[RowID], [ResultPage].[HasPending], [Current2].[ID] As [Current2^ID], [Tag].Name], 
etc... etc...
FROM [ResultPage] 
INNER JOIN [Current]  ON ([Current].[ID] = [ResultPage].[ID]) 
 INNER JOIN [Current2] ON ([Current].[T2ID] = [Current2].[ID]) 
 WHERE (([ResultPage].[RowID] BETWEEN -1 AND 50)) ORDER BY [ResultPage].[RowID] ASC
```

Comment: sorry this looks mental. Can you explain what it tries to achieve?

Comment: Yeah that looks wrong, so wrong.

Comment: i would materialize the results of that query into a temp table, and then join to the temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with the help of Jacco's suggestion and modifying it to give the right results I am after, I was able to get it running, cutting the query down to an astonishing 1sec...

```
WITH [ResultPage] AS 
(SELECT
    sub.id as id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [sub].[hasPending] DESC, [sub].[ID] ASC) AS [RowID],
    [sub].[hasPending]
 FROM
(
SELECT
    a.[ID],
    (CASE WHEN p.[CID] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [hasPending]
FROM [Alarm] a

full outer JOIN [Pending] as p
    ON a.[ID] like p.[CID] 
GROUP BY a.[ID],p.[CID]
) AS [sub]
INNER JOIN [Current2] ON (sub.[T2ID] = [Current2].[ID]))
SELECT [ResultPage].[RowID], [ResultPage].[HasPending], [Current2].[ID] As [Current2^ID],
etc...etc...
 FROM [ResultPage] 
INNER JOIN [Current] ON ([Current].[ID] = [ResultPage].[ID]) 
INNER JOIN [Current2] ON ([Current].[T2ID] = [Current2].[ID]) 
WHERE (([ResultPage].[RowID] BETWEEN -1 AND 50)) ORDER BY [ResultPage].[RowID] ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess having a double subquery is quite expensive. It might perform better if you determine the `[hasPending]` in a single subquery and save on some `JOIN`'s.

```
SELECT
    [sub].[ID],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [sub].[hasPending] DESC, [sub].[ID] ASC) AS [RowID],
    [sub].[hasPending]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Current].[ID],
        (CASE WHEN COUNT([pending].[ID]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [hasPending]
    FROM [Current]
    INNER JOIN [Current2] 
        ON [Current].[T2ID] = [Current2].[ID]
    LEFT JOIN [Pending] 
        ON [Current].[ID] = [Pending].[ID] AND [Pending].[User] = 'Admin'
    GROUP BY [Current].[ID]
) AS [sub]
```

*Edit:* Changed `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT([pending].[ID])` in order to determine `[hasPending]` correctly.

Comment: The current to current2 table join might be one to many and you would be eliminating rows so this might not be right if that is the case.  In the case that admin and someone else is the user in question you would get 2 rows in the join.  One that has pending and one that doesn't have pending.

Comment: Never mind, I'm wrong.  It's basically the same query as the second one I wrote just a little less complex.

Comment: thanks, I tried running the query with my data, and haspending came up true on each and every line, even though there is only supposed to be 8.

Comment: Turns out its a Full Outer join that is needed instead of a left join, and then the HasPending can be determined by checking if the id field is null or not

Comment: That's probably wrong too. what you need is to change the (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) to (CASE WHEN pending.id is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) because the count is always going to be greater than 0 since the only way it wouldn't is if the row didn't come back.

Comment: My bad, you guys are right. It should have been COUNT([pending].[ID]), this will return the expected 0 if nothing is found.

Comment: I have added a solution below using jacco's suggestions, I found I had to use Full Outer join to get the data I needed, otherwise I would only get all records without pending, I need records from both tables, however only the ones from current that are not in pending and visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, this should speed it up since the ids will be dumped to a table variable and not have to be queried every single loop.  This is most likely not the best solution but without further info about what you are trying to do this should at least help.

```
declare @ids table
(
    id int
)

insert into @ids(id)
SELECT [ID] From [Pending]
Inner Join [Current] On [Current].[ID] = [Pending].[ID] 
WHERE ([Pending].[User] = 'admin')

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY Case When [Current].[ID] In (select id from @ids) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, [Current].[ID] ASC) As [RowID], 
    [Current].[ID], 
    Case When [Current].[ID] In (select id from @ids)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [HasPending] 
FROM [Current] 
INNER JOIN [Current2] AS [Table2] ON ([Current].[T2ID] = [Table2].[ID])
```

You could also use this if your ids are unique which I assume they are:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY a.haspending, a.[ID] ASC) As [RowID],
    a.id, a.haspending,
from (select [Current].[ID], 
      Case when a.id is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [HasPending] 
        FROM [Current] 
        INNER JOIN [Current2] AS [Table2] ON ([Current].[T2ID] = [Table2].[ID])
        left join  (SELECT distinct [ID] From [Pending]
                    Inner Join [Current] On [Current].[ID] = [Pending].[ID] 
                    WHERE ([Pending].[User] = 'admin')) a on a.id = [Current].[ID]) a
```

Comment: thanks, no matter how I twist this, the sql manager will not accept this code, I tried removing the , before from (select, however its still complaing about the last )